# Initializing Lua state in C

Tags: c, lua

I'm trying to use Lua (5.2) from my C code. I'm creating a Lua state and calling "luaL_openlibs", but global function such as "loadstring" aren't initialized.

```
lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
luaL_loadstring(L, "print(loadstring)");
lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
```

Result is: nil. Simple Lua code works (for example, print("hello")), so does the standard libs (strings, ...). Please help me to figure out what am I doing wrong, i've been searching google for a couple of hours and all I found were those weird old mail-lists and Lua documentation (which is also not very helpful, IMO).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/) is always very useful. As you can see in the table at the bottom, there is no `loadstring` in Lua 5.2, the closest is `load`. Also if you check section 8.2 of that manual,  *Changes in the Libraries*, you can see an item regarding loadstring that was available in 5.1, saying incidentally that `loadstring` has been replaced by `load`, same functionality.

Changing the source should always be a last resort ie only if there is no other way. Here, what you want is easily doable via the C API:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "load")
lua_setglobal(L, "loadstring")
```

Even in cases where you don't use C (just straight Lua), you can do `loadstring = load` at the top of the script. Or `setenv LUA_INIT "loadstring=load"` in a console or `.bashrc`, then Lua executes this for every script it runs (from that console). Or run your script as `lua -e'loadstring=load' yourScript.lua`. Am I missing any? :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found this in the comments:

```
@@ LUA_COMPAT_LOADSTRING defines the function 'loadstring' in the base
** library. You can rewrite 'loadstring(s)' as 'load(s)'.
```

So after defining that const I could use "loadstring" :)

Comment: Instead of rebuilding Lua, just do `loadstring=load` with say `luaL_dostring("loadstring=load")`.

Comment: better yet, use `load` directly